# Android Overlays for drawing shapes in Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, overlay, shapes, itemizedoverlay

I want to draw several shapes (over 40) for separated zones in a city and I am not sure what is the best way to do this. I am considering drawing the shapes using:

- ItemizedOverlay.
- Overlay: One overlay for all shapes.
- Overlays: One overlay for each shape.

What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't been using ItemizedOverlay so can't say anything about it but if you are to choose between Overlay and Overlays - take one Overlay for all items.

One overlay is one canvas and one draw method. One overlay for each object are multiple canvases and drawing methods. This is pointless.

You should use different overlays only when you create "layers" which can be visible or not (as a whole layer) like Google Satelite or Google Street View.